# Performance/good practice comparison on calling variable or entity field

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, variables

I need to know if it's heavier or a bad practice if i use the variable **id** i'm passing via request to an Action in a Controller or use the Model's IdFoo i retrieved using the same id i once passed via the same request.

Let's suppose i'm using ASP.NET MVC4 with C# and Entity Framework, and i have this Model with it's Data Annotation, declaring **IdFoo** as the Primary Key for the Model:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int IdFoo { get; set; }
}
```

In my **FooController**, in the **Edit** action, i need to retrieve the IdFoo, but it's the same as the **id** variable i'm passing via route.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int id = 0)
    {
        var Foo = db.Foo.Find(id);

        // Other operations.

        var Bar = Foo.IdFoo;

        var Qux = id;

        // Bar = Qux

        ...

        return View(Foo);
    }
}
```

Is it a good practice/less performance intense to still keep using the **id** variable i'm passing via the request for the rest of the controller code, or should i use **Foo.IdFoo** for it? Note that Foo.IdFoo and id will always have the same value, so i know i can use both, i'm just looking for good practices or performance reasons to justify the use of one or another.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `IdFoo` is doing something it shouldn't, it should make no difference whatsoever from a performance point of view.

From a micro-optimization stand point, I imagine it would *technically* be faster to use a variable that's already in the context rather than pulling it from the `Foo` object; but that's really splitting hairs and I have no benchmarking statistics to prove that theory.

Comment: Imagine that i will have to retrieve `Foo`from the database with `db.Foo.Find(id)` every time, so we can't escape this part. The thing i'm saying is: Forgetting about the fact that i already retrieved `Foo` and after i already did that, is there any difference in using `Foo.Id` or the variable `id`? More technically, does simply calling  `Foo.Id`, already **loaded** in the server's RAM memory, is more practical and/or performance intensive than simply calling the `id` variable, **ALSO** stored in the server's RAM memory?

Comment: @EdgarSalazar Like I said, there is possibly some *slight* overhead going into the property given it's an extra function call. However, your talking fractions of milliseconds...if any. Stick with whichever is the most readable to you because in terms of performance there will be no visible difference.

Comment: So, i think I'll create our own team's good practice for this case, it's been happening a lot in our projects. I'll stick with Foo.Id and leave id for Entity's retrieve only. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any difference in performance. However, there are two other considerations:

- What if the variable or the property is modified? A thousand commits later, one of this operations might end up changing the Id of that object. Or may be this won't be any of these operations, but something in the other thread. So, in case of this (now unlikely) behavior it would possibly be better to use the property. By the way, I don't know the specifics of ASP.NET, but your ID property looks like it's not supposed to change over the lifetime of the project, so it would probably be wise to make this property read-only (without an accessor), so it would only be set in constructor.
- What is more readable? Right now both options look the same, but in the real world these class names often get long, so simple id would probably be better.

Comment: **Foo.Id** is the correspondent to the Primary Key field on the Database. Generally, it's auto increment.

Comment: You must know that all this code is happening inside a HTTP GET request in ASP.NET MVC4, and `Foo.Id` and `id`, even thou they are changeable in the code, shouldn't ever he changed to the end of the request lifetime because there's no reason for ever do it. This application shouldn't ever deal with changing or generating Primary Keys, in this case it's the Database's responsibility, app will only retrieve and query on it (like you can see in the `db.Foo.Find(id)` part, we're retrieving the Entity from the Database with LINQ (Language Integrated Query).